# How should I store image data in a Java Bean class?

Tags: java, image, javabeans, rmi

I am working on a Java project after a *very* long time of not having used the language, so bear with me (I'm primarily a .NET and Windows Forms developer nowadays, as some background).

I am creating some [Java Bean classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11406977/3775798) to store related data which will be passed between separate Java processes on my local machine through RMI. Some of these processes will act as clients and expose a GUI to the user (most likely Swing-based).

Let's say I have a Java Bean which represents information for a driver's license. Among other things like the license number and information about the driver, one of the properties should be a photo of the driver. This photo will be displayed in a GUI and set by the client's user, and may also have to be stored in a database by another process at some point.

In C#, I would use the [System.Drawing.Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx) class to store this information. But what should I use in a Java Bean? Again, I haven't used Java in a long time to develop a project, so I'm quite rusty; I'm sure this is something simple, but a quick web search is not giving me anything.

Comment: You may want refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel)

Comment: Simplest would be [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html), something more flexible might be [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/). You should also have a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

Comment: @TuyenNguyen and others: Just to be clear, this question is primarily about the class I would use in a Java Bean. Then using this image in a Swing GUI is secondary. What I use may or may not be the same for both, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: You can save it as a string path to your image, a file or an byte[], then in Swing GUI just load it and draw

Comment: @TuyenNguyen A `String` path or a file is not feasible in my case, because the image data needs to be contained within an object sent to another process via RMI (i.e., the file may not be accessible on the other end if one of the processes is relocated to another host).

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton so you can use an array of byte to save this image data, you can send it to every where you want then [convert this byte array to image](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-byte-to-bufferedimage-in-java/)